# Is there any other way to implement plotly R’s cumulative animation?

Tags: r, animation, plotly, r-plotly

```
accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

d <- txhousing %>%
  filter(year > 2005, city %in% c("Abilene", "Bay Area")) %>%
  accumulate_by(~date)
```

If you implement a cumulative animation in the manner of the function above, the number of rows will increase too much.

I use a thousand frames and a row of ten thousand. Because of the large number of data, the work in progress has been disturbed.

https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/

Is there any way to create a cumulative animation other than the example?
Help me!

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently facing the same issue. The approach described [here](https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/) is not applicable for a few thousand rows of data.

**I don't have a fully working solution**, but my idea was to adapt the x-axis range based on the slider value instead of re-using the data for each frame (see example plot `p_range_slider`). This unfortunately doesn't provide us with the "Play"-button.

I thought it might be possible to use `animation_slider()` in a similar way but the `steps` argument passed to `animation_slider()` is not evaluated (see example plot `p_animation_slider`). The steps remain tied to the animation frames (as stated in `?animation_slider`).

Update: this behaviour is *intended by design* see the [sources](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/animate.R):

```
  # don't let the user override steps
  slider$steps <- steps
```

Also building a `subplot` of both sharing the x-axis wasn't successful.

```
library(plotly)

DF <- data.frame(
  n = 1:50,
  x = seq(0, 12, length = 50),
  y = runif(n = 50, min = 0, max = 10)
)

steps <- list()

for (i in seq_len(nrow(DF))) {
  steps[[i]] <- list(
    args = list("xaxis", list(range = c(0, i))),
    label = i,
    method = "relayout",
    value = i
  )
}

# Custom range slider -----------------------------------------------------

p_range_slider <- plot_ly(
  DF,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers"
) %>% layout(title = "Custom range slider",
       xaxis = list(range = steps[[1]]$args[[2]]$range),
       sliders = list(
         list(
           active = 0, 
           currentvalue = list(prefix = "X-max: "), 
           pad = list(t = 20), 
           steps = steps)))

p_range_slider


# Animation slider --------------------------------------------------------

p_animation_slider <- plot_ly(
  DF,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  frame = ~ n
) %>% layout(title = "Animation slider") %>% animation_slider(
  active = 6,
  currentvalue = list(prefix = "X-max: "),
  pad = list(t = 20),
  steps = steps # custom steps are ignored
)

p_animation_slider

# subplot(p_range_slider, p_animation_slider, nrows = 2, margin = 0.05, shareX = TRUE)
```

It seems for this approach to work `animation_slider()` would need to allow it's `steps` argument to perform custom actions (untied from the defined frames). Any other Ideas to approach this are highly appreciated.

Maybe it is possible to reproduce [this](https://community.plot.ly/t/animation-produces-extremely-large-files/14812/8) approach for the python api using a filter (avoids axis-rescaling) in R? - [Filter in R](https://plot.ly/r/filter/)

Here is an example on how to use filter transform and a custom range slider in R, however, still no animation (without precomputing each frame):

```
DF <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 2), y = runif(20), group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 10))

steps <- list()

for (i in seq_along(unique(DF$x))) {
  steps[[i]] <- list(
    args = list('transforms[0].value', i),
    label = i,
    method = "restyle",
    value = i
  )
}

p_filter_slider <- plot_ly(
  DF,
  x = ~ x,
  y = ~ y,
  color = ~ group,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "lines+markers",
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = 'filter',
      target = 'x',
      operation = '<=',
      value = ~ x
    )
  )
) %>% layout(title = "Custom filter slider",
             xaxis = list(range = c(0.5, length(unique(DF$x))+0.5)),
             sliders = list(
               list(
                 active = 0, 
                 currentvalue = list(prefix = "X-max: "), 
                 pad = list(t = 20), 
                 steps = steps))
             )

p_filter_slider
```

[image: Result]

---

**Additional Infos:**

animation_slider [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.8.0/topics/animation_opts)

JS slider [attributes](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/sliders/attributes.js)

Related GitHub [issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/957)

RStudio Community [question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotly-alternative-implementation-of-cumulative-animations/31290)

Here is the same [question](https://community.plot.ly/t/is-there-any-other-way-to-implement-rs-cumulative-animation/9729) on the plotly forum.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. We had thousands of data points per minute, so as a first step I just made another column called "time_chunk" which just rounded the time to the minute.

Then I accumulated by the time_chunks instead of the very precise minute data (with decimal places). That gave me a more reasonable number of chunks.

The animation is not completely smooth but our data is approximately 20-40 minutes long, so it's reasonable and processes quickly.

So, theoretically:

```
fig <- fig %>%
mutate(time_chunk = floor(time_min))

fig <- accumulate_by(fig, ~ time_chunk)
```