# keep line graphs after the frame ends in r ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to create an interactive plot. My lines have different frames (some end shorter). When I play the animation, the lines disappear after their frame ends. I tried to add more rows of fake data with the added frames but that didn't make a difference. I am not sure why this is happening.

Sample Data:

```
> dput(sample_n(Plot, 20))
structure(list(Strain = c(0.0114976650717703, 0.0283627375, 0.00173272727272728, 
0.0150241, 0.0450557, 0.0113663, 3.97637e-05, 0.0434292, 0.00406928, 
0.00207895693779905, 0.000215139, 0.00148572499999999, 0.0418233875, 
0.000939926, 0.000255219, 0.0213334, 0.023816, 0.0145059, 0.0131467081339713, 
0.0668966), Stress = c(75.9505644091148, 78.5302055162329, 48.6062116858257, 
68.4024611345473, 85.2904610049016, 63.9140059100703, 1.43583171490823, 
84.8256506176318, 64.1272033757161, 53.8795512181689, 14.442082799196, 
64.3587637619208, 84.731707366194, 25.4200560130662, 13.8571035440045, 
84.1313452985436, 85.4161843153761, 67.9158653588222, 77.7143709896995, 
90.4239965485986), Instrumentation = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("DIC", "LVDT"), class = "factor"), Bar = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Spliced", "Unspliced"), class = "factor"), 
ANIM = c(0.01, 0.03, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.07), frame = c(0.05, 
0.05, 0.04, 0.13, 0.05, 0.1, 0.01, 0.11, 0.02, 0, 0.04, 0.11, 
0.09, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 0.06, 0.09, 0.05, 0.08)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The frames are created by the function:

```
accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}
```

I have the following for the plot:

```
plot <- ggplot(Plot) + aes(x = Strain, y = Stress, colour = Instrumentation, linetype = Bar, frame = frame) +
 scale_color_manual(values = c("DIC"="red", "LVDT"="blue")) + geom_line(size = 0.8) + theme_classic() + 
 labs(x = "Strain (in/in)", y = "Stress (ksi)") + 
 theme_classic() + theme(axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 16), 
   axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
   axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
   axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
   legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 16))


ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  tooltip = c("Strain","Stress","Instrumentation","Bar"),
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE,) %>% animation_opts(frame = 300, transition = 0, easing = "linear", redraw = TRUE) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Stress (ksi)", standoff = 30L), spikesides = TRUE,spikethickness = 1),
         xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Strain (in/in)",standoff = 30L), spikesides = TRUE,spikethickness = 1),
         legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 0.7, y = 0.13)) %>% animation_slider(hide = TRUE)
```

Also, the redraw doesn't seem to do what I want. I want the plot to start with the complete graph (last frame and all lines) and then also end with everything completed. I only want the animation when pressing the play button.

**EDITED:**

The initial data is comprised of multiple dataframes. I accumulated the frames for each dataframe independently and then collected them in a single dataframe with `rbind`.

```
> dput(sample_n(Plot.Spliced_DIC, 5))
structure(list(Strain = c(0.00635239, 0.00646411, 0.00304078, 
0.00104394, 0.00138191), Stress = c(64.9199586945409, 65.0674673934705, 
60.7649363239015, 26.5627079525764, 39.4159208404832), Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DIC", class = "factor"), Bar = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Spliced", class = "factor"), ANIM = c(0.01, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> dput(sample_n(Plot.Unspliced_DIC, 5))
structure(list(Strain = c(7.66444e-05, 0.112481, 6.7294e-05, 
0.00275991, 0.0600871), Stress = c(0.00344797841982851, 92.8897366602444, 
0.522824377824084, 64.3513766859271, 88.2700702030104), Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DIC", class = "factor"), Bar = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Unspliced", class = "factor"), ANIM = c(0, 
0.11, 0, 0, 0.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> dput(sample_n(Plot.Unspliced_LVDT, 5))
structure(list(Strain = c(0.071858225, 0.0020442, 0.01736605, 
0.0259565, 0.025441275), Stress = c(90.4766041042011, 60.701740404307, 
70.0774864366534, 76.21702132901, 75.9110679987475), Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "LVDT", class = "factor"), Bar = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Unspliced", class = "factor"), ANIM = c(0.07, 
0, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

> dput(sample_n(Plot.Spliced_LVDT, 5))
structure(list(Strain = c(0.0238954832535885, 0.00040463157894736, 
0.0158640956937799, 0.0224346507177033, 0.00269568421052631), 
Stress = c(85.3207044456991, 14.881393139828, 79.7864191978379, 
84.4980682215488, 56.6941352672259), Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "LVDT", class = "factor"), Bar = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Spliced", class = "factor"), ANIM = c(0.02, 
0, 0.02, 0.02, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Plot.Spliced_DIC <- Plot.Spliced_DIC %>% accumulate_by(~ANIM)
Plot.Unspliced_DIC <- Plot.Unspliced_DIC %>% accumulate_by(~ANIM)
Plot.Unspliced_LVDT <- Plot.Unspliced_LVDT %>% accumulate_by(~ANIM)
Plot.Spliced_LVDT <- Plot.Spliced_LVDT %>% accumulate_by(~ANIM)

Plot <- rbind(Plot.Spliced_DIC, Plot.Unspliced_DIC, Plot.Unspliced_LVDT, Plot.Spliced_LVDT)
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a [cumulative animation](https://plotly.com/r/cumulative-animations/)?

Comment: @ismirsehregal yes

Comment: @ismirsehregal If you look at the edit I just included, I already have the `accumulate_by` function

Comment: Can you please provide us with the initial dataset?

Comment: @ismirsehregal just edited to show the original data

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues regarding your above approach:

1. you need to call `accumulate_by` after using `rbind`
2. There seems to be a bug when using the `tooltip` argument along with an animation (traces are disappearing - I therefore commented it out)

Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

Plot.Spliced_DIC <-
structure(list(Strain = c(0.00635239, 0.00646411, 0.00304078, 0.00104394, 0.00138191),
               Stress = c(64.9199586945409, 65.0674673934705, 60.7649363239015, 26.5627079525764, 39.4159208404832),
               Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DIC", class = "factor"),
               Bar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Spliced", class = "factor"),
               ANIM = c(0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Plot.Unspliced_DIC <-
structure(list(Strain = c(7.66444e-05, 0.112481, 6.7294e-05, 0.00275991, 0.0600871),
               Stress = c(0.00344797841982851, 92.8897366602444, 0.522824377824084, 64.3513766859271, 88.2700702030104),
               Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DIC", class = "factor"),
               Bar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Unspliced", class = "factor"),
               ANIM = c(0, 0.11, 0, 0, 0.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Plot.Unspliced_LVDT <-
structure(list(Strain = c(0.071858225, 0.0020442, 0.01736605,0.0259565, 0.025441275),
               Stress = c(90.4766041042011, 60.701740404307, 70.0774864366534, 76.21702132901, 75.9110679987475),
               Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "LVDT", class = "factor"),
               Bar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Unspliced", class = "factor"),
               ANIM = c(0.07,0, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Plot.Spliced_LVDT <-
  structure(list(Strain = c(0.0238954832535885, 0.00040463157894736, 
                            0.0158640956937799, 0.0224346507177033, 0.00269568421052631), 
                 Stress = c(85.3207044456991, 14.881393139828, 79.7864191978379, 
                            84.4980682215488, 56.6941352672259), 
                 Instrumentation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "LVDT", class = "factor"),
                 Bar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Spliced", class = "factor"), 
                 ANIM = c(0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

plotData <- rbind(Plot.Spliced_DIC, Plot.Unspliced_DIC, Plot.Unspliced_LVDT, Plot.Spliced_LVDT)
plotData <- plotData %>% accumulate_by(~ANIM)

lastFrame <- with(plotData, plotData[frame == max(frame),])
lastFrame$frame <- -1

plotData <- rbind(lastFrame, plotData) # prepend last frame to show all complete traces in the beginning

plot <- ggplot(plotData) + aes(x = Strain, y = Stress, colour = Instrumentation, linetype = Bar, frame = frame) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("DIC"="red", "LVDT"="blue")) + geom_line(size = 0.8) + theme_classic() + 
  labs(x = "Strain (in/in)", y = "Stress (ksi)") + 
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 16), 
                          axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
                          axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
                          axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
                          legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 16))

ggplotly(
  p = ggplot2::last_plot(),
  width = NULL,
  height = NULL,
  # tooltip = c("Strain","Stress","Instrumentation","Bar"), # bug?
  # tooltip = c("x","y","colour","linetype"), # bug?
  dynamicTicks = FALSE,
  layerData = 1,
  originalData = TRUE) %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 300, transition = 0, easing = "linear", redraw = TRUE) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Stress (ksi)", standoff = 30L), spikesides = TRUE,spikethickness = 1),
         xaxis = list(title = list(text = "Strain (in/in)",standoff = 30L), spikesides = TRUE,spikethickness = 1),
         legend = list(orientation = "v", x = 0.7, y = 0.13)) %>% 
  animation_slider(hide = TRUE)
```

[image: result]

By the way the approach to create cumulative animations using `accumulate_by` will [turn slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871541/is-there-any-other-way-to-implement-plotly-r-s-cumulative-animation/55922974#55922974) with more data. [Here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/957#issuecomment-596532439) you can find another approach to create a cumulative animation by filtering the data. However, the R plotly package currently doesn't allow providing custom steps for animation sliders.
Please support my [FR](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1719) if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you! The tooltip bug is because we didn't have frame as one of the inputs. if changed to `tooltip = c("Strain","Stress","Instrumentation","Bar","Frame"),` it runs with no problems

Comment: I thought you don't want the `frame` in the tooltip. Adding it to the definition results in the same behaviour as not specifiying the tooltip argument at all. Nevertheless, good that it is working for you!